# iText7 OverflowPropertyValue not triggering overflow

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am running into an issue with iText7 and I cannot figure it out. I am creating a table of data with iText7, due to the format of the PDF I need some cells to allow overflow on the x axis to display the full text, but when I set the property of overflow x it does not work and I can't find any reason why.

Here is the code I have, any advice is appreciated:

```
    cell = new();
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(availableCreditText);
    cell.Add(paragraph);
    paragraph.SetProperty(Property.OVERFLOW_X, OverflowPropertyValue.VISIBLE);
    cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    cell.SetFontSize(6);
    cell.SetHeight(8);
    cell.SetBorderBottom(new SolidBorder(1.0f));
    stopTable.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!